# Pandas: Applying '&' operator in df.query(), in mutiindex scenario

Tags: pandas, multi-index

How to use the `&` operator in `df.query()` for same index in multi-index
 data frame. e.g in my data frame named 'movie_genre'.

I have three indexes -> `[id, title, genre]`. Now I want to access all the id & title wherein genre is 'Comedy' & 'Drama'. I am using

```
df.query('(genre=="Comedy") & (genre=="Drama")')
```

but it is returning blank result.

Comment: ```df.query('genre == ["Comedy", "Drama"]') ```

Comment: I had given it a try, but it is throwing a mix result. like OR operator. e.g  records with only Comedy, records with Comedy & Drama (right one), records with Comedy + other genre.

Comment: kindly share some data with expected output